# How do I bind a OO class's variables to text boxes?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a class named Product in a C# WinForms project, which is defined as follows:

```
class Product
    {
        string pName;
        string pType;
        string pSubType;
        string pBarcode;
        string pRegion;
        string pComments;
        bool pEnabled;

        // methods here ...
    }
```

Now I have a form in which I'm using one instance of this Products class. Now I want to avoid manually binding the data between this Product class instance and the text boxes in the form. Is there any better way to do this, other than to manually assign values to and fro .. ?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Yes, with a whole bunch of reflection and string manipulation based on TextBox `Name`s or `Tag`s. But I wonder if it's worth the effort (or truly a "better" way).

Comment: You should probably refactor out the code into a methods, i.e. a `SetFormFromProduct` and `GetProductFromForm` methods.  Beyond that, manually implementing those methods is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

Change your private fields to [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface, and use the [databindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) you can add to controls, and there you go.